# External monitor output halts after switching sources on monitor

Tags: arch-linux, multi-monitor, monitors

I have several machines plugged into an external monitor, one of which is a laptop running arch.

I can switch sources on the monitor to toggle between these three different systems. But if I stay on a non-arch system for too long, when I switch back to arch there is no output on the external monitor. I have to run some xrandr scripts ( one to move/change the display, and one to restore it ) then it starts sending the video signal to the monitor again. I have mapped these scripts to shortcuts in i3, but it still seems a little too hacky.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. The other machines do not have this issue, they continually send the video signal out to the monitor regardless of whether that source is selected or not.

It seems arch system can tell that the monitor does not have it selected as a source, then disconnects the display after a few seconds.

Is there some way to force output to the external monitor regardless of the selected source on the monitor?

Comment: What kind of monitor / videocard combination do you use? I have the same problem with a GeForce / Iiyama combination. What xrandr scripts do you use? Even those would be very welcome to have!!

Comment: Right now, I've been restarting gdm over SSH, but that makes me lose all of my apps.